# Finding the Laurent series of a function at $z=i$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

The question asks me to find the Laurent series of $$f(z) = {5z+2e^{3z}\over(z-i)^6}\,\,at\,\,z=i$$I know the following $$e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^n\over n!}$$ What I want to know, is if I can do this: $$={1\over (z-i)^6}\sum_{n=0}^\infty ({2(3z)^n\over n!}+5z)$$  $$=\sum_{n=0}^{n=6}(z-i)^{n-6}({2(3z)^n\over n!}+5z)+\sum_{n=7}^{\infty}(z-i)^{n-6}({2(3z)^n\over n!}+5z)$$
This is all I could think of possibly doing and I'm not even sure if it is even something that I can even do, and I don't really know how to continue. I also need to find the radius of convergence but I feel once I have the series it will be easy to apply whatever test necessary to acquire it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting
$$ 5z+2e^{3z}=5(z-i)+5i+2e^{3i}e^{3(z-i)}==5(z-i)+5i+2e^{3i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(z-i)^k $$
one has
$$ f(z) = {5z+2e^{3z}\over(z-i)^6}={5i\over(z-i)^6}+{5\over(z-i)^5}+2e^{3i}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}(z-i)^{k-6}.$$

Comment: Can I split the summation into singular and analytic parts as well? with $$2e^{3i} \sum_{k=0}^{5}{(z-i)^{k-6}\over k!}$$ being the singular part and analytic part follows?

Comment: @Heavenly96, you can do that.

Comment: And the radius of convergence would be anything besides $z=i$?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of problem I recommend changing the variable to push the pole to zero. Here I'd set $w=z-i$. The problem becomes:
find the Laurent series of
$$g(w)=\frac{5(w+i)+2e^{3w+3i}}{w^6}$$
at $w=0$. The numerator is
$$5i+5w+2e^{3i}\left(1+3w+\frac{3^2w^2}{2}+\frac{3^3w^3}{3!}+\cdots\right)$$
etc.

Comment: wouldn't it be $2e^{3w+3i}$?

Comment: @Heavenly96 corrected, thanks!

Comment: No, thank you :) Also, I thought finding the radius of convergence would be easy but it isn't as easy as I expected due to the terms adding outside the sum. How do I do this?

Comment: The exponential series converges everywhere, so your Laurent series will converges everywhere save of course at the pole $z=i$.